# Greping exact match/substring

Tags: regex, bash, grep

I have a set of words which looks like:
**fruits.txt**

```
APPLE,2  
apple,3  
APPLE-ORANGE,3  
APPLEORANGE-GRAPE,5
```

and trying to print "apples" only.

here is what i've tried and almost all the commands with similar problem return the same output as follows:
`grep -iE "apple\b" fruits.txt`
APPLE,2
apple,3
APPLE-ORANGE,3 ##this is the extra line which i want to ignore

also i've tried the following, but didn't return anything.
`grep -i '^apple$' fruits.txt`

**EXPECTED OUTPUT**
APPLE,2
apples,3

PS: Please don't suggest on `grep -iE 'apple\b' fruits.txt | grep -v "-"` I can't use this in a loop in case of greping "APPLE-ORANGE", again It'll be a problem.

Comment: why cant we grep `apple,`

Comment: there is a plan to implement this along with `grep -w`; I've `apple,` as my last option.

Comment: Are you looking for solutions that involve grep? if not you can use bash parameter expansion..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try:

```
grep -i 'apple[ ,]' fruits.txt 
grep -iP 'apple\b(?=[\s,])' fruits.txt
```

from the

```
APPLE,2
apple,3
APPLE-ORANGE,3
APPLEORANGE-GRAPE,5
applE , 8
AAple900
```

both prints

```
APPLE,2
apple,3
applE , 8
```

Both regexes search for case insensitive *apple* followed by at least one  (space) or `,`.

if you don't want accept  (space) just remove the character groups...

Or, you should say to `grep` what isn't allowed to follow the `apple`, like:

```
grep -iP 'apple[^\w-]' fruits.txt
grep -iE 'apple[^[:alnum:]-]' fruits.txt
```

search for `apple` what isn't followed by any *word character* or `-`.

Comment: That's cool ! correct answers with explanation. Learnt a new thing :) Thanks mate !

Answer (score 2):

You could use `awk` for this task:

```
$ awk -F, -v IGNORECASE=1 '$1 ~ /^apple$/' fruits.txt
APPLE,2  
apple,3
```

If you want to pass `awk` a shell variable to be used, you could do this:

```
$ fruit=apple
$ awk -F, -v IGNORECASE=1 -v FRUIT="^$fruit\$" '$1 ~ FRUIT' fruits.txt
APPLE,2  
apple,3
```

Comment: Wonderful !! It works well ! and I have a quick question; how can i use it in a loop, i meant instead of `apple` how can i use a variable like `$fruit`. I tried `awk -F -v FRUIT=$fruit,IGNORECASE=1 '$1 ~ /^FRUIT$/' fruits.txt`. But no luck.

Comment: @ManivG You're welcome, glad to help!  `awk` treats text inside `/.../` as part of a regular expression, so it can't expand a named variable.  To get around that, you can place the regex special characters in the variable definition and leave out the `/.../`.  See the solution added in my recent edit.